# Detect which condition is false in multiple if statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I try to shorten my code, and so I come along to shorten the following type of if statement:

```
// a,b,c,d needed to run
if ( empty(a) ) {
    echo 'a is empty';
} elseif ( empty(b) ) {
    echo 'b is empty';
} elseif ( empty(c) ) {
    echo 'c is empty';
} elseif ( empty(d) ) {
    echo 'd is empty';
} else {
  // run code with a,b,c,d
}
```

Is there a way to detect which one of the conditions was false (is emtpy)?

```
if ( empty(a) || empty(b) || empty (c) || empty(d) ) {
     echo *statement n*.' is empty';
} else {
  // run code with a,b,c,d
}
```

I thought about a for loop, but that would need massive code changes.
Maybe someone can point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance :)

Jens

Comment: I don't know.
Maybe the for loop is not a bad idea
declare a array with the vars and do the id inside the for, with a break.
Or if you want you can show 'a', and 'c' are empty...

Comment: you actually mean, which statement is `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `compact`, `array_filter` and `array_diff`:

```
$arr = compact( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' );
if( count( $empty = array_diff( $arr, array_filter( $arr ) ) ) )
{
    echo key( $empty ) . ' is empty';
}
else
{
    echo 'OK';
}
```

By this way, in `$empty` you have all empty values. So you can echo a warning for all keys:

```
echo 'Empty: ' . implode( ', ', array_keys( $empty ) );
```

Comment: This was the easiest solution, as I have a various amount of variables to handle, and they all come into the function, so I just need to copy the function call into $arr

Answer (score 4):

You can go with setting a variable for each condition and output this

```
if ( (($t = 'a') && empty($a)) || (($t = 'b') && empty($b)) || (($t = 'c') && empty($c)) || (($t = 'd') && empty($d)) ) {
     echo "{$t} is empty";
} else {
  // run code with a,b,c,d
}
```

The assignment (`$t='a|b|c|d'` ) will always be true and it the testet var is empty your condition will fail because of `true && false` in the condition

But in terms of readibility i would rather go with any of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of condition I would recommend you to use **switch**, which is more optimised way of doing it, like this:

```
$empty = "";
switch ($empty) {
    case $a:
        echo "a is empty"
        break;
    case $b:
        echo "b is empty"
        break;
    case $c:
        echo "c is empty"
        break;
    default:
        echo "nothing is empty";
}
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and his code ?

Comment: Performance of switch statement better then if statement, because it is faster then specially if there are more and more number of conditions, because with if the code will check & than move to the next condition. With a switch, though, each comparison is going to be a test for equivalence, and the only thing that changes is the value that you're comparing to.

Comment: I totally agree with this answer, a switch statement will perform better.

Comment: I understand that the question might not be asked directly for the performance but there is no harm in suggesting something which will perform better, he wanted to shorten the code & by shortening the code we want to decrease the no of lines of code which needs to be interpreted, which indirectly affects the performance of the code. Also, switch is more clearer than if if the no. of conditions is high.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd probably use a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). But this is just cos I like them, some don't

```
// the variables somewhere else in your code
$a = 1;
$b = null;
$c = '';
$d = 4;


// do your check
$arr = ['a','b','c','d']; // the names of the variables you want to check

foreach($arr as $var) {
    if(empty($$var)) {
        echo $var . ' is empty'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Will output

> b is empty
>   c is empty

[example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/19b411015bec769a5bf99a89187a5ad54bb56936)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
<?php 
$arr = array('a'=>1,'b'=>2,'c'=>null,'d'=>4); //make an array of variables
echo "Null variable : ".array_search(null, $arr); // check for null item
?>
```

This will Output :

```
Null variable : c
```