# What condition was false in the if statement

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement

I'll give you the general idea of what I'm asking, it is similar for this: [Detect which condition is false in multiple if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36891191/detect-which-condition-is-false-in-multiple-if-statement).

Let's say that I have this if statement:

```
if (1 > 2 && 2 < 3 && "hello".equals("Hello"))
```

How do I check which condition was false, and which was true?
Similar to e.printStackTrace();

Comment: If they're all pure expressions, you can just copy the condition and print the result. Is that not sufficient? Doing that in a debugger would even tell you all the values involved automatically.

Comment: Well, I want to know if I can check it all at once and then print what went false. @Carcigenicate

Comment: You can use the java debugger to evaluate the expression in different combinations or all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ideal choice is to use the debugger to evaluate each of the statements. 
However, if you want to print the result, you could extract each of the checks into their own variable and then print their result:

```
boolean firstCheck = 1 > 2;
boolean secondCheck = 2 < 3;
boolean thirdCheck = "hello".equals("Hello");

System.out.println("First check is: " + firstCheck);
System.out.println("Second check is: " + secondCheck);
System.out.println("Third check is: " + thirdCheck);

if (firstCheck && secondCheck && thirdCheck) {
    //Do something
}
```

Comment: Yea, but like I said to the other user, I want to know if it's possible to check it all at once, and then print what was false.

Comment: There is no way that I know of to dynamically print which of the statements was false. You could however use an array to store all of the statements you want to check.